# Translating strings outside react components using react-18next

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, localization, i18next, react-i18next

a lot of tutorials and articles that show how to add i18n to react applications using react-18next, have the translatable strings inside the components. Why does it seem like its an accepted convention yet this could potentially lead to code duplication and prove to be a maintenance nightmare for a sufficiently large codebase.

- Are there patterns that in react-js ecosystem that can help one organize such translatable strings much better, bearing in mind that they should be reactive to run-time language changes by the user on the browser.
- Would the solution work where some of the strings have to be defined outside the components, e.g though contrived

```js
// utils
export const lookup = {
  key1: {
    title: 'lorem Ipsum', // values should be translated
    description: 'a somehwat long description',
    severalOtherProps: 'and their values',
  },
  // ... several keys here.
  lastkey: {
    title: ' lorem Ipsum',
    description: 'a somehwat long description',
    severalOtherProps: 'and their values',
  },
};

// component1.tsx

export const component1 = () => {
  // consumes lookup
};

export const component2 = () => {
  // consumes lookup
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may benefit from re-reading more of the [i18n docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/essentials):

Specifically about `namespacing` and `nesting` of translations.  All of the translation `key:value` pairs **are** defined OUTSIDE of the react component. You use the translation functions provided, like `useTranslation` in your react component.

If you have a helper function outside of your component, you would have to pass `t` as an argument to be consumed within the function, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand that in pure javascript this type of convention (having the translatable strings inside the components) leads to very poor developer experience, in typescript, I think this is acceptable since there is no way that a translation key is not defined or contains a typo and everythings autocomplete out of the box.
For maintenance, there are tools like [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner) that handle maintaining all your translations with just a single terminal command, which removes the hell of maintaining that by hand.

On the other hand, having a helper function to handle translation keys is a lot of boilerplate IMO but can be acceptable if you are using pure JS. In this case, you can use translation by passing `t` as a parameter of the helper function or use `i18next.t('myTranslationKey')` in the function, knowing that there is a little chance that the language updates won't be taken in account directly

---

Just in case someone is looking for how to consume translation outside of a react component (which the title suggests):

```js
import i18next from 'i18next'

i18next.t('myTranslationKey')
```